# What's the difference between @observable and @published in polymer.dart?

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

In polymer.dart, if you want to expose a variable defined in controller to the view side, you define the variable with `@observable` and use double mustache to embed the variable. However, some docs and tutorials use `@published` to meet the same purpose. The official docs also uses both, so I don't think `@published` is legacy and deprecated way of defining variables.

So is there any difference between the two? And which one should I use in my code?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**@published - is two way binding ( model to view and view to model)**

Use case for @published is ,if your model property is also attribute in a tag.

Example : For a table-element you want to provide data from external source ,so you'll define attribute data,in this case data property should be @published .

```
<polymer-element name = "table-element" attributes ="structure data">
     <template>
         <table class="ui table segment" id="table_element">
             <tr>
                 <th template repeat="{{col in cols}}">
                     {{col}}
                 </th>
             </tr>
             <tr template repeat="{{row in data}}">
              etc......
     </template>
<script type="application/dart" src="table_element.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>


@CustomTag("table-element")
class Table extends PolymerElement {

 @published  List<Map<String,String>>  structure; // table struture column name and value factory
 @published List<dynamic> data; // table data
```

**@observable - is one way binding - ( model to view)**

If you just want to pass data from  model to view use @observable

Example : To use above table element i have to provide data ,in this case data and structure will be observable in my table-test dart code.

```
<polymer-element name = "table-test">
 <template>
     <search-box data ="{{data}}" ></search-box>
     <table-element structure ="{{structure}}" data = "{{data}}" ></table-element>
 </template>
<script type="application/dart" src="table_test.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

dart code

```
CustomTag("table-test")
class Test extends PolymerElement {

  @observable List<People> data = toObservable([new People("chandra","<a href=\"http://google.com\"  target=\"_blank\"> kode</a>"), new People("ravi","kiran"),new People("justin","mat")]);
  @observable List<Map<String,String>> structure = [{ "columnName" : "First Name", "fieldName" : "fname"},
                                                     {"columnName" : "Last Name", "fieldName" : "lname","cellFactory" :"html"}];
  Test.created():super.created();
```

Examples are taken from [My Repo](https://github.com/chandu0101/dart-polymer-elements-with-angular)

Comment: Thanks. Then when is the case to use @published? Even if I use only one-way connection, I can achieve it with @observable, right? Is it a bad convention or lose some performance?

Comment: Thanks for the terrific clarification. And I just found that I misunderstood `@published` and `@observable` in my first comment here... Sorry.

Comment: Hi, here: https://www.dartlang.org/codelabs/polymer/#create-model  in the 'Key information' column, point #3 there is written that '@observable' is two way binding. Please can you clarify this?

Comment: basically ```@observable``` makes the item being observed in a two way binding (so if you use it in a double moustach scenario in an input changed to the item will be reflected in the input and changes in the input reflected on the item. ```@published``` is the same but on top of that exposes the item to be used as an attribute from users of your element. At least that is what I understand ...